# My django form fields are not showing up in template

Tags: python, django, forms

forms.py

```
class ImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Image
            fields = {'title', 'url', 'description'}
            widgets = {
                'url':forms.HiddenInput,
            }


        def clean_url(self):
            url = self.cleaned_data['url']
            valid_extensions = ['jpg', 'jpeg']
            #The two below codes do exactly the same thing but partition is faster
            extention = url.rpartition('.')[2].lower()
            #extension = url.rsplit('.',1)[1].lower()
            if extension not in valid_extensions:
                raise forms.ValidationError('The given URL does not match valid image extensions')
            return url


        def save(self, force_insert=False,force_update=False,commit=True):
            image = super(ImageCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
            image_url = self.cleaned_data['url']
            image_name = '{}.{}'.format(slugify(image.title), image_url.rpartition('.')[2].lower())
            #download image from the given URL
            response = request.urlopen(image_url)
            image.image.save(image_name,ContentFile(response.read()),save=False)

            if commit:
                image.save()
            return image
```

*The image appears alright but the fields are not showing*

**index.html**

```
    {% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Bookmark an image{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Bookmark an image</h1>
<img src="{{ request.GET.url }}" class="image-preview">
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ forms.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value= 'Bookmark it!'>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: did you define "forms" in your views?

Comment: In your template you have `{{ forms.as_p }}`. Usually, I would expect `{{ form.as_p }}` (without the s). You haven't shown your view, so I can't tell whether or not this is the problem.

Comment: Yes I did 'form = ImageCreateForm(data=request.POST)}'

Comment: post your views code so that its easy for us to understand

Comment: Yes Alasdair I looked at it but still not working

Comment: Post the code of your views.py file. Where is the function where you render the template with the form inside. I think you forgot to define "forms" so its not showing up...

Comment: It is below in the answers sections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your form to this

you pass the fields in `list` and not `set` type `{}`

```
class ImageCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Image
            fields = ['title', 'url', 'description']
            widgets = {
                'url':forms.HiddenInput,
            }
```

in your views

```
def image_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #form is sent
        form = ImageCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #form data is valid
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            new_item = form.save(commit=False)

            #assign current user to the item
            new_item.user = request.user 
            new_item.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Image added successfully')

            #redirect to new created item detail view
            return redirect(new_item.get_absolut_url())

    else:
        #build form with data provided by the bookmarklet via GET
        form = ImageCreateForm()

    return render(request, 'images/image/index.html',{'section':'images', 'form':form})
```

and in html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Bookmark an image{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Bookmark an image</h1>
<img src="{{ request.GET.url }}" class="image-preview">
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value= 'Bookmark it!'>

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It still shows up only image no field, after passing it to a **list**

Comment: post your views from where you are passing the form @ragemon

Comment: @ragemon you are passing the form to create.html but you have your form listed in index.html, so try the edited ans, hope it will help

Comment: Yes I did but I still have the same problem

Comment: copy the view and paste it in your views file, it will work now @ragemon

Comment: A big thanks @Exprator it work this time around when I pasted it. I just had to change index.html to which create.html which was my original template name. Thanks again

Comment: glad could help @ragemon, thanks for bearing with me

Answer (score 0):

Although it does not look like it, make sure that the if request.method and its related else are on the same level. I sometimes get the else indented to match the if form.is_valid level.